# How to construct a DFA which accepts all the strings endig with aa and no two consecutive b (bb)

Tags: graphs, finite-automata, strings

I have to construct a DFA which ends with aa and does not contain any pair of b-s. A = {a,b}, {aa,baa,aaa,abaa,babaa,...}. I know how to construct them as separate DFAs but not together merged.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to construct DFAs for two languages separately, you can use systematic methods to build the DFA which recognises the intersection of the languages (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147457/intersection-of-two-deterministic-finite-automata). However to achieve a minimalist and elegant result (as well as for learning purposes) you may want to try and find ad-hoc methods.
NB: You can always apply a DFA minimization procedure to 'clean up' the automaton obtained via the above general method (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization).

Comment: Once you have any DFA implementing the desired behavior, you can create a minimal DFA from it via any of the well-known DFA minimization methods. This does not require any ad-hoc reasoning, and the computational cost is tiny for DFAs this small.

Comment: Yes you are right, my comment on minimality isn't really relevant. Still I think that it can be instructive to try and build a DFA from scratch, in preparation for the day where the DFA is too large.